# Что нужно прочитать?

Tags: операторы, c++

Скажите на милость, какой раздел надо изучить/прочитать, чтобы стало понятно, как работать с такими объявлениями методов, и что значит " pointer operator -> ()"?

```
class unique_ptr
    {
        using pointer = T*;
        using reference = T&;
        using Deleter = std::function<void(pointer)>;

        pointer ptr;
        Deleter deleter;

        struct default_deleter
        { void operator () (pointer p) { delete p; } };

    public:
        unique_ptr() noexcept : ptr(nullptr), deleter(default_deleter()) {}

        unique_ptr(pointer p, Deleter del = default_deleter()) : ptr(p), deleter(del) {}

        unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;

        unique_ptr(unique_ptr &&x) noexcept : ptr(x.ptr), deleter(x.deleter)
        {
            x.ptr = nullptr;
        }

        ~unique_ptr()
        {
            deleter(ptr);
        }

        unique_ptr& operator = (const unique_ptr&) = delete;

        unique_ptr& operator = (unique_ptr &&x) noexcept
        {
            ptr = x.ptr;
            x.ptr = nullptr;
            deleter = x.deleter;
            return *this;
        }

        reference operator * () const
        {
            return *ptr; // !!! *nullptr
        }

        pointer operator -> () const noexcept
        {
            return ptr;
        }

        pointer get() const noexcept
        {
            return ptr;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это называется "c++ перегрузка операторов". В гугле очень хорошо ищется. Вот к примеру статья с [хабра](http://habrahabr.ru/post/132014/).

Answer (score 0):

Шилд базовый курс C++. В книге дается хорошая база.